# Tabulator : Stretch Last Row

Tags: tabulator

In Tabulator there is an option for the columns to "Fit Columns to Data and Stretch Last Column".

I would like a similar behaviour for rows, the last row stretching to fit the table and fill the height.

The height and data in my table are dynamic so my desired behaviour:

1. if there are more rows than can fit in the parent div show scroll bars
2. if the height of the parent div is more than the number of rows, then stretch the last one

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an available option in Tabulator, and i would argue it would make for terrible UI as stretching the row could lead to all sorts of unpleasant side effects depending on the formatter you are using.

There are two more visually appealing options that may work

#### Background colour

It would be far better to change the background colour of the table to match the row colour so that you still achieve that full table look without stretching a row:

```css
.tabulator{
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

#### Max Height

If you are concered about too much whitespace in the table, then instead of defining a table height, you could define the `maxHeight`, that way the table would scroll when there was enough rows and shrink when there aren't.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    maxHeight:300, //maximum height for the table is 300px
});
```